# Function in generic class

Tags: scala, generics

I have class Seq and I want to have method "multy" that adds number to List factors, but I want, that only Seq of Number types will have this method, for this example, val numbers should work with multy, and val strings shouldn't.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object Main extends App{
  val strings = new Seq("f", "d", "a")
  val numbers = new Seq(1,5,4,2)
  val strings2 = new Seq("c", "b")
  numbers.multy(5)
  strings.multy(5)
  val strings3 = strings2.concat(strings)
  println(strings3)
  println(numbers)
}


class Seq[T : Ordering] (initialElems: T*) {
  override def toString: String = elems.toString

  val factors = ListBuffer[Number](1)

  val elems = initialElems.sorted

  def concat(a:Seq[T]) = new Seq(a.elems ++ this.elems:_*)

  def multy[T <: Number](a:Number) = {
    factors += a;
  }
}
```

Comment: What should `multy` do for types that are not supported?

Comment: `scala.Int`, `scala.Double`, etc are not subclasses of `Number`

Comment: My idea, is that "multy" wouldn't be supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `scala.Int`, `scala.Long`, `scala.Double`, etc to not be supported - because they don't extend `Number` - you can define method as

```
def multy(a: Number)(implicit ev: T <:< Number): Unit = {
  factors += a
}
```

However, considering that under the hood they could be extending `Number` (if the compiler, decides that it should compile them as objects and not as primitives), usage of a type class would work better:

```
trait IsNumber[T] {
  def asNumber(value: T): Number
}
object IsNumber {
  implicit def numbersAreNumbers[T <: Number]: IsNumber[T] = t => t

  implicit val intIsNumber: IsNumber[Int] = i => (i: Number)
  ... // the same for Long, Short, etc
}
```

which could be used in multy as evidence

```
def multy(a: Number)(implicit ev: IsNumber[T]): Unit = {
  factors += a
}
```

and as normal type class in code that would need that knowledge for something:

```
def doSomethingWithElements(implicit isNumber: IsNumber[T]) = {
  elems.map(isNumber.asNumber).toList // List[Number]
}
```

This would support both `java.lang.*` `Number`s as well as Scala's numbers definitions.

Comment: If I need only scala Int, Double, Float to be for multy, what can I use instead AnyVal (because it contains boolean for example) 
def multy(a: Number)(implicit ev: T <:< AnyVal):

Comment: Why not just using the built in **Numric** typeclass?

Comment: `Numeric` doesn't expose method of casting to `java.lang.Number` that OP might want. It allows casting directly `.toLong`, `.toDouble` etc, which could change the value underneath. If this `Number` x `Number` semantics is not needed (I assume it is because `factors` are `Number`s) and OP would be OK with `factory: List[T]` (empty if T is not Numeric) and appending to it only if `T` is Numeric, then yes, `Numeric` would be sufficient.